# How can a theme or preference avoid graying-out a background window when a non-model dialog is open?

Tags: gnome, eclipse, dialog

When I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find a string in Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2), the code in the  background gets grayed out. I asked [on  StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309794/how-can-i-keep-my-code-visible-in-eclipse-while-searching?noredirect=1#comment95439719_54309794) and learned that this is most likely an Ubuntu feature.

As I step through the text with Find, I want to see the found text.

How can I keep the background window from being "grayed out" while the dialog is open?

Note that other dialogs do the same: For example, If I choose  *Help->Install New Software*, the background is grayed out.

How can the graying-out be limited via theming or via Ubuntu preferences so that it only works on modal dialogs, but is avoided on non-modal dialogs?

On Ubuntu 18.10 (GNOME Shell, using `gdm`, `$DESKTOP_SESSION` is `ubuntu`)
[image]

Comment: The question is, can the graying-out be limited via theming or via Ubuntu preferences to modal/blocking dialogs, but avoided on non-modal/non-blocking dialogs?

Comment: In KDE this is very easy to do on a per application basis; it's not entirely clear to me what your DM is but https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/891/windows-blur-effects/ allows changing background effects, but it sounds like it doesn't remove all blur.

Comment: This is now no longer a problem with Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) & ubuntu 19.10.